# Explode string at first alphanumeric character

Tags: php, explode

I have a strings like this.

```
$str = "-=!#?Bob-Green_Smith";

$str = "-_@!?1241482";
```

How can I explode them at the first alphanumeric match.
eg:

```
$str = "-=!#?Bob-Green_Smith";

becomes:

$val[0] = "-=!#?";
$val[1] = "Bob-Green_Smith";
```

Quick thought some times the string won't contain the initial string of characters,

so I'd need to check if the first character is alphanumeric or not.. otherwise Bob-Green_Smith would get split when he shouldn't.

Thanks

Comment: You could use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with a limit I guess!?

Comment: The characters can be I any order and may not all be in the string. Sometimes the string may not contain any of the initial characters.

Comment: Do you need the initial characters or can they just be removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_match`.

This will match "`non word characters`" zero or more as first group.
Then the rest as the second.

The output will have three items, the first is the full string, so I use `array_shift` to remove it.

```
$str = "-=!#?Bob-Green_Smith";
Preg_match("/(\W*)(.*)/", $str, $val);
Array_shift($val); // remove first item
Var_dump($val);
```

https://3v4l.org/m2MCg

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_split()` because you literally want to split the string into an array.  Match the position of the first occurring alphanumeric character, then only split once.  To ensure two element are always created, unite a fallback array with a 2-element array containing empty strings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KDOZC))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/(?=[[:alnum:]])/', $test, 2) + ['', '']
);
```

Or use a pattern to match then "forget" the leading non-alphanumeric characters. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/LN0JY))

```
var_export(
    preg_split('/[^[:alnum:]]*\K/', $test, 2) + ['', '']
);
```

Tests:

```
$tests = [
    "-=!#?Bob-Green_Smith",
    "-_@!?1241482",
    "8675309",
    "#!",
];
```

Results:

```
array (
  0 => '-=!#?',
  1 => 'Bob-Green_Smith',
)
array (
  0 => '-_@!?',
  1 => '1241482',
)
array (
  0 => '',
  1 => '8675309',
)
array (
  0 => '#!',
  1 => '',
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this like :

```
$str = "-=!#?1Bob-Green_Smith";
preg_match('~[a-z0-9]~i', $str, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $bubString = substr($str, $match[0][1]);
```

Comment: you can check now.